# Why am I getting repeating decimals?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason, Python is giving me incorrect results when subtracting certain floats such as `4.35-8.55` or `5.945-9.465`. These are interpreted as `-4.200000000000001` and `-3.5199999999999996`, respectively. It is obvious that the results should be `-4.2` and `-3.521, as I get with other calculators. This is bewildering--why am I getting a truncated repeating decimal for non-repeating rational numbers? Does anyone else get these same results?

Comment: I guess I won't be using Python for a calculator anymore...

Comment: _"I guess I won't be using Python for a calculator anymore"_ Clearly you haven't read the first answer in that topic.

Comment: @AllanBurleson if you need arbitrary precision, you need to use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library. It's amazing to me how often this comes up, because this should be common knowledge to any programmer that *binary* floating point will always have problems representing *decimals.*

Comment: Go ahead and open your browsers dev tools and open the console tab and enter `.1 + .2` and see what answer you get OP.

Comment: @Rawing It hadn't been marked as a duplicate yet.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm fairly new to programming; I didn't know that.